# IntelliJ: Cannot open SBT Project: jansi 1.11 error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

Having very recently started working with Big Data, I'm looking to learn more about Spark and Scala to learn to work with many files and hdfs. While experimenting with IntelliJ (which was recommended to me), I installed the most recent update of IntelliJ along with an installation of SBT as well as the Scala plugin.

However, I seem to have encountered a problem, when I open an idea project in Scala, it works without any issues, however, if I try to open an sbt project, I encounter the following error:

TL;DR Something called Jansi 1.11 is not with the file.

```
Error while importing sbt project:

Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11  (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

==== local: tried

C:\Users\user_name\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml

-- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

C:\Users\user_name\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar

==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

file:/C:/Users/user_name/.sbt/preloaded/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

==== local-preloaded: tried

file:/C:/Users/user_name/.sbt/preloaded/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

-- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

file:/C:/Users/user_name/.sbt/preloaded/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

==== Maven Central: tried

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

-- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

==== sbt-maven-releases: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-    releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

-- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-    releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

==== sbt-maven-snapshots: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

-- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path     building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
(see C:\Users\user_name\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11`
```

Is there a way to fix this? I've already tried reinstalling multiple times.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? If so, check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981320/scala-sbt-and-corporate-proxy-suncertpathbuilderexception

Answer (score 1):

I landed here after facing the same issue (behind corporate proxy and getting this same error message). I tried all the suggestions mentioned in multiple (related) threads but was able to finally resolve it by setting up the HTTP Proxy directly in IntelliJ. Here's what my settings look like (Note: specify your network username and password in the corresponding boxes):-

[image]