# Unresolved dependencies upon attempt to run sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Attempting to follow the examples in the O'Reilly "Programming Scala" book.
Downloaded then installed sbt with:  brew install sbt@1
Appears to have succeeded.
Upon then typing "sbt" or "sbt -v" at the command line (bash on Mac) I get:

```
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: com.eed3si9n#sjson-new-scalajson_2.12;0.8.2: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

:::: ERRORS
        Server access Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12/0.8.2/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12-0.8.2.pom
...
followed by numerous similar "Server access Error: PKIX path building failed:" messages.

Any suggestions welcome.

Glen

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981320/scala-sbt-and-corporate-proxy-suncertpathbuilderexception

I would install scala and sbt through direct downloads, preferably the intelliJ package, it works really well. https://www.scala-lang.org/download/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala sbt and corporate proxy - SunCertPathBuilderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981320/scala-sbt-and-corporate-proxy-suncertpathbuilderexception)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing the latest version of sbt via `brew install sbt`.

Since sbt will always download the correct version of itself and scala for a given project, installing the latest version on your computer should be fine.