# Security is Blocking SBT & JVM - How to Import SSL Certificates via .pem File

Tags: java, scala, jvm, ssl-certificate, sbt

My company has installed a bunch of new security stuff on my machine that I don't understand (zscalar, appgate sdp, other stuff), but it's blocked most of the internet.  I need to use a .pem file that includes some certificate info that lets me through the firewalls or whatever.  (it's over my head what's happening)

One thing that has broken is the SBT / JVM stuff.  When I try to use SBT to compile a fat jar, it fails with the following error:

`[error] Server access Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.el/`

I use `SDKMan` to manage java versions, and I use `sbt assembly` to package up fat jars (some projects use sbt 0.13, some use 1.3).  Laptops are macbooks (one old, one new).

I tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981320/scala-sbt-and-corporate-proxy-suncertpathbuilderexception), but it makes no difference.  Same error before & after.

```
# myRootCA.pem is in ~/.myCert/
cd ~/.myCert
cp $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts ~/.myCert/
keytool -keystore cacerts -import -file myRootCA.pem -alias myProxy

# tried before & after restarting machine; no difference
cd <scala repo>
sbt  "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=~/.myCert/cacerts" assembly
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I get that .pem file of CA certificates into the JVM in a way that let's me use SBT
2. Can I get that into an `sbtopts` file somewhere (in individual repo's or /usr/local/etc/ or elsewhere) so I don't need an unwieldy addition to all my sbt commands

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me and resolved both points 1 & 2 was to just modify the `cacerts` file directly instead of copying it, modifying it, and pointing to the copy.  Now SBT works fine with no additional arguments.

```
keytool -importcert -file myRootCA.pem -alias myRootCA -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass 'changeit'
```

I think if I need to back it out, this would work.

```
keytool -delete -alias myRootCA -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass 'changeit'
```

I don't know if this is the best idea, but it works, so I'll go with it for now.